# proving that we don’t need more than n bits to represent F(n)

Tags: proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove that for Fibonacci numbers, we don't need more than n bits to represent F(n), where F(n) is the nth Fibonacci number.

For this, I got that the closed-form
$F(n) = \frac{\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}$

The number of bits required to represent a decimal number $N$ is $log_2(N)+1$

Number of bits would be $log_2(F(n))+1$
$log_2(\frac{\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n}{\sqrt5})+1$
$log_2(\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n)-log_2(\sqrt5))+1$

but how do i proceed further

mainly with simplifying $log_2(\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n)$

Comment: $|1-\phi|<1$, so asymptotically speaking you could approximate $\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n\approx\phi^n$ and go from there. Then you could manually check for the cases of smaller $n$, perhaps?

Comment: Use the recursion formula to show that $F(n)<2^n$ for $n\ge 1$.